# How to solve Import Error when no circular dependency exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, importerror

Here is my import structure:

inputs.py (It includes user inputs and it calls the simulator where simulator runs)

```py
from simEngine import simulator
# user inputs
simulator(A, B)
```

simEngine.py

```py
import Building
import ResidentArrivalSetup
def simulator(A, B):
    building = Building(...)
    residentArrival = ResidentArrivalSetup(...)
```

Building.py

```py
import inputs
class Building:
    def __init__(self, blaBla)
        self.blaBla = blaBla
        self.residentDic = {}
```

ResidentArrivalSetup.py

```py
import Resident
import Building
class ResidentArrivalSetup:
    def __init___(self, C):
        self.C = C
        self.building = Building(residentDic) # Class composition
  
    def someMethod(self):
         resident = Resident(K,L,M)
```

Resident.py

```py
import inputs
  
class Resident:
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.buildingHeight = inputs.buildingHeight
```

1. When I run the inputs.py, it gets the input from the user and it calls `simulator` function.
2. Then `simulator` calls `Building` and `ResidentArrivalSetup` classes (`Building.py` is constructed from the `inputs.py`).
3. `ResidentArrivalSetup` creates an instance of `Resident`. `Building` has a dictionary where I store the `Resident` instances when I create a Resident from `ResidentArrivalSetup` . So, I import that dictionary by importing `Building` into `ResidentArrivalSetup`.

When I run the `inputs.py`, I get

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'simulator' from 'simEngine'
```

I added the current path to the sys.path already.  How can I solve this?

[My visual class architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h03pJ.png)

Comment: It is obviously a circular import. `inputs` imports `simEngine`, `simEngine` imports `Building`, and `Building` imports `inputs`. You can even see the circles in your class diagram.

Comment: The most important rule to prevent circular imports in Python: Do not import the module you are executing anywhere!

Comment: Alright. Then I have a misunderstanding of circular dependency. Any idea how I can fix this? @Selcuk

Comment: Yes, don't import `inputs.py` anywhere as @KlausD. suggested. If you are importing your main executable you have a logic error in your design. Your main module (`inputs.py` in your case) should delegate functionality to other packages/modules/classes/functions; not the other way around.

Comment: @Selcuk Thank you very much to both of you. Much appreciated!

Comment: also one thing that might help - if you can, import specific functions/classes/variables, don't import the entire file as a module. that helps minimise your likelihood of circular imports. so instead of ``import inputs``, import specific functions/classes from ``inputs.py`` if you REALLY need to

Comment: @wasiqam great advice. Thank you very much!

Comment: @wasiqam That will not mitigate the circular import problem since the whole file will be executed anyway.